# Set up and Login to wifi via command line

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, wifi

I am setting up an script that will set up my Linux system as I like whenever I reinstall the distribution (I actually end up doing this quite alot).

I can do most things such as move my panel, set my colour scheme etc. But I am having problems automating the login to the wifi. I am currently at uni so the wifi is "eduroam" and hence the procedure to set it up manually is rather time consuming:

> 1. Click the wifi applet-> network connections -> Add -> Wifi
> 2. Set connection name
> 3. Then proceed to change settings on the "Wifi" and "Wifi Security" tabs including adding a certificate and login.

I have tried looking at how to automate this in command line (i.e. a .sh script) but can't seem to find anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nmcli.html) command.

Comment: @IporSircer Cool, thanks. At a first glance it looks like this should do the trick. I will have a go to see if I can get it working.